# Potentiometer reading out letters

Tags: serial, potentiometer

My potentiometer reads out t's or u's in my serial.
I believe that my potentiometer is wired correctly.
What am I missing?
Here is my code:

```
#include <VarSpeedServo.h>

VarSpeedServo servo;
const byte buttonLeft = 2;
const byte buttonRight = 3;
const int led = 7;
const int potentioPin = A0;
int potentioVal = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(11);

  // PIN MODES
  pinMode(buttonLeft, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonRight, INPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  // INTERRUPT
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonLeft), turnServo, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  int stateBtnLeft = digitalRead(buttonLeft);
  int stateBtnRight = digitalRead(buttonRight);

  if(stateBtnLeft == 0 && stateBtnRight == 0){
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}

void turnServo(){
  Serial.println("Button was pushed");
  potentioVal = analogRead(0);
  Serial.write("Servo moving with speed ");
  Serial.write(potentioVal);
  Serial.println("");
  //servo.write(180, potentioVal, true);
  //Serial.write("Reached position of motor");
  //lightLed();
}

void lightLed(){
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Serial.print instead of Serial.write.

Answer (score 3):

`write()` is a function for binary data. I you want to print the number as text, use `print()` or `println()`.

`Serial.println(potentioVal);`